# Using structs and the char* is corrupted but the other data fields aren't?

Tags: c

So I've basically made a struct to accept five data fields, four of which are ints and the other is a char*. After having giving each their own value, anytime I try to use the char* I only recieve corrupted results, yet whenever I use the ints I don't have an issue. Can anybody correct me on my mistake because I'm not sure what it is.

Header file: rph.h

```
typedef struct
{
    float HP;
    float ATK;
    float DEF;
    float MED;
    char* name;
} Heros;
```

Code where structs get there value:

```
void tokenizeHero(char* str, Heros* hero)
{
    char* piece = strtok(str, ",");
    hero->HP = atof(piece);

    piece = strtok(NULL, ",");
    hero->ATK = atof(piece);

    piece = strtok(NULL, ",");
    hero->DEF = atof(piece);

    piece = strtok(NULL, ",");
    hero->MED = atof(piece);

    piece = strtok(NULL, ",");
    hero->name = piece;
}
```

The variable str in this will look like
20,6,3,1,Arlen

Comment: Great candidate for stepping through in a debugger to see where things go off the rails. You probably want to duplicate the string, too like `hero->name = strdup(piece)` presuming that string is NUL terminated *and* recycled.

Comment: `hero->name = piece;` does **not** make a copy of the string. Try `hero->name = strdup(piece);` instead.

Comment: `name` points to part of the string that was originally passed to `tokenizeHero()`. If that string is reused for something else, `hero->name` will point to the new value.

Answer (score 2):

You assign `hero->name` from `piece` and you get that from `str`. That means that as soon as you change `str` (from the function that calls `tokenizeHero()`) your `str` changes. Yet you stored a pointer to part of it in `hero->name`. Not good.

Change it to `hero->name = strdup(piece);` and make sure you release it when you're done with your `hero`. Or change `name` into an array and use `strlcpy(hero->name, piece, sizeof(hero->name))`.

Answer (score 1):

If the input string is some sort of buffer that's recycled then you'll corrupt the buffer each time you re-use it and those pointers you copy will be useless.

The easy fix is to duplicate the string:

```
hero->name = strdup(piece);
```

Where you are now responsible for freeing that memory when disposing of that struct.

Comment: I go to use this, however I'm told it's an implicit declaration and also assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Oh, when using `strdup` don't forget to include the header file for it. This almost goes without saying. `#include <string.h>` When using any function you need to check what header it comes from, that's something you'll need to internalize as a habit when writing C code.

Comment: @Nick When you see warnings that contain _"implicit declaration"_, consider it as an error. Include `<string.h>` and try again.

Comment: The warning _"assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast "_ is also almost always an error.

Comment: I'm not kidding, even including the <string.h> header, I'm still getting the identical errors

Comment: @Nick It's possible that `strdup` is not available on your system. In that case, write your own. `char *strdup(const char *str) { char *copy = malloc(strlen(str)+1); strcpy(copy, str); return copy; }`

Comment: @user3386109 if you where in my physical area, I'd find out how germaphobic you are and then kiss you repeatedly, thank you so much. Definitely not something I would've thought of. Only issue, I think it's giving me a new line character, is there anyway to get rid of that?

Comment: @Nick Changing the last `strtok` to `piece = strtok(NULL, ",\n")` should fix the newline.

Comment: If `strdup()` is missing you should specify what compiler/OS you're using as that function has been around for decades and is really not that exotic.